# Send push notifications with Firebase Messaging from several servers

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, firebase-admin

I have server application which is sending push notification  using Firebase Messaging. I have Firebase service account for that. Code is very simple and looks like the following:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(credentials)
        .build();
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp);
```

and sending like:

```
String messageId = firebaseMessaging.send(...);
```

I am using [firebase-admin-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java)
I have several servers with this application and all of them will send push notification.
The question is

1. Can I use the same service account from several servers simultaneously?
2. Are there any limitations/quotas for service accounts in Firebase Messaging(how many IP addresses can use it, how many requests per IP or per account, etc.)?
3. Can I use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) to send push notifications from servers?

Comment: 2. FCM doesnt have any kind of limit or quota when it comes to the number of messages you could send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can. As long as each server is able to generate an access token you should be fine. See [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/blob/master/messaging/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/Messaging.java#L45)
2. No, there are no limitations on FCM. FCM can be limited if abuse is discovered. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/):

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a cross-platform messaging solution
>   that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost.

3. No, FCM Auth only supports [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) Access Tokens. FCM Legacy API supports an API key which is available from the Firebase console.